# Can I regenerate the rsa key for SSH access to a Cisco router? Or should I completely erase the SSH config?

Tags: ssh, cisco, configuration, router

I have a production 2691 that I administer via telnet.  I'd like to change that to SSH.  Looking at the config, it looks like there have been keys generated in the past.  I think the history here is SSH was set up, they had issues connecting, and fell back to telnet.

There are a number of `crypto` entries, including the following:

```
crypto pki trustpoint Gateway-2691.xxx.com
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Gateway-2691.xxx.com
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair Gateway-2691.xxx.com
```

I've also got this going...

```
Gateway-2691#sh ip ssh
SSH Disabled - version 1.99
%Please create RSA keys (of atleast 768 bits size) to enable SSH v2.
Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3
Gateway-2691#
```

My question is simply, can I run `crypto key generate rsa` again to set it up again?

Is there a way to negate or `no` all of the previous ssh config so that I can start fresh there?

I may be asking the wrong questions, as I'm learning here.  As for the SSH how-to, I'm sure I can find information in many places.  I'm just basically wondering if I need to start  fresh, or if I can pick up where the last attempt at SSH config left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `show crypto key mypubkey rsa` to see if you do, in fact, have a key fully generated and registered under a non-default name.  If there is, then you can tell the ssh process to use this key with `ip ssh rsa keypair-name xxx`.  If the first command doesn't show anything useful then I'd say you can go ahead and generate a new key.

You don't list your complete ssh configuration, so it's hard to know what to remove.  Try `sh run | inc ssh` to see what's in there.  In general ssh will start to work as soon as the process has a valid key.  Remember that you may need to add authentication and, possibly, vty configuration if they aren't in place.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  Nothing showed up running your `show` cmd there, so I created a new key.  `ssh` up and running now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the previous key with the following command.

```
cisco(config)# crypto key zeroize rsa
```

Then sanitise the vty lines.

**Simple SSH Config**

```
cisco(config)# hostname <name>
cisco(config)# ip domain-name <domain>
cisco(config)# crypto key generate rsa
cisco(config)# ip ssh version 2
```